# javascript to enable checkbox and check it

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I remove the check and disable a checkbox with:

```
$('#h12_1').removeAttr('checked');
$("#h12_1").prop("disabled", true);
```

I then want to enable it again and then check it.

```
$('#h12_1').removeAttr('disabled');
$('#h12_1').attr('checked','checked');
```

The above syntax reenables the checkbox but does not check it.

Am I missing something? help appreciated as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of this

`$('#h12_1').attr('checked','checked');`

try something like this

```
$('#h12_1').prop("checked",true);
```

Comment: (and to uncheck: `$('#h12_1').prop("checked", false);` )

Comment: Thanks Sachin, appreciated.